# The request failed or service did not respond in a timely fashion 2014 SQL server // SQL server agent cannot start

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent

["The request failed or service did not respond in a timely fashion."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsjx9.png)

[TCP/IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbGKJ.png)

I have some problems, i have downloaded microsoft SQL server 2012 and it was working perfectly fine before, using my `local server` (my own computer). but there's this day, it decided to not connect for me. so i went to google, searched on how to solve this problem.

- adjusted the inbound to accept `port 1443`.
- disable `TCP/IP` and enabling it again (tested both ways).
- uninstall `SQL server 2012` multiple times and reinstalling it again.
- check service where both `SQL browser` and `SQL server` is there.
- downloaded `SQL server 2014` instead.
- tried `localname\SQLEXPRESS`
- find server name using `SQLCMD -L`
- SQL server agent start mode to `automatic`

what else could be wrong? 
it couldn't start still...

Comment: You need to look into the [`errorlog`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885(v=sql.105).aspx) file. It will contain the error which explain the reason.

Comment: 2017-01-07 03:17:31.74 spid18s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2017-01-07 03:17:31.74 spid18s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2017-01-07 03:17:31.76 spid18s     Service Broker manager has started.
2017-01-07 03:17:31.77 spid8s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

Comment: Looks like SQL is running OK, is it just SQL Agent that won't start?

Comment: yes. i believe it is just the SQL agent...

Comment: Look for a file called SQLAGENT.OUT (the sql agent error log file), it may give you more information. Otherwise the OS System and/or Application logs in event viewer could help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: 2017-01-07 04:44:27 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
2017-01-07 04:44:27 - ! [000] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229)
2017-01-07 04:44:27 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)

sorry.. i do not understand what it meant. is it something i should remove?

Comment: Looks like your SQL Server Agent service is running as the wrong service account. Read and follow [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Yes. It was thank you! :)